# Load nested YAML/JSON documents using Serde

Tags: rust, serde

I have a `struct Source` and a `struct License`, where a source can hold n licenses and a license can belong to m sources. Now I would like to load the sources from yaml configuration files:

```
---
url: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.32.tar.xz
signature: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.32.tar.xz.sig
licenses:
- gpl_2_0
```

The licenses are referenced via a string identifier, which can be used to fetch the license configuration from `licenses/<id>/<id>.yaml` (eg. `example/licenses/gpl_2_0/gpl_2_0.yaml`):

```
---
short: GPLv2
name: "GNU General Public License, version 2"
url: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
```

All licenses should be collected in one vector and references to them should be placed in the result struct instead of the string identifier.

```
use serde_yaml;

mod licenses;
mod sources;

use packages::Sources;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let config = std::fs::File::open("sources/binutils/config.yaml")?;
    let doc: Source = serde_yaml::from_reader(&config)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

And the corresponding structs for sources

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Source {
    url: String,
    signature_url: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "from_license_ids")]
    licenses: Vec<License>,
    target: String
}
```

and licenses.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct License {
    id: String,
    short: String,
    name: String,
    url: String
}
```

Now I have tried to use the deserialize_with hint to call a custom deserialize function:

```
fn from_license_ids<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<License>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let license_ids: Vec<&str> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    let mut licenses: Vec<License> = Vec::new();

    for license_id in license_ids {
        let path = format!("example/licenses/{0}/{0}.yaml", license_id);
        let config = std::fs::File::open(&path)
            .map_err(D::Error::custom)?;
        let mut license: License = serde_yaml::from_reader(&config)
            .map_err(D::Error::custom)?;
        license.id = license_id.to_string();
        println!("{:?}", &license);
        licenses.push(license);
    }

    Ok(licenses)
}
```

Which fails as the `struct License` is in a seperate file and thus the fields are private, which I can only fix by adding a setter for id or making the id field public. Is there a better way to make the struct accessible within the sources.rs file? However this still leaves me with this error:

```
Error: Message("invalid type: string \"gpl_2_0\", expected a borrowed string", Some(Pos { marker: Marker { index: 208, line: 9, col: 4 }, path: "sources[0].licenses[0]" }))
```

Second approach was to define a custom deserializer:

```
struct LicenseVisitor;

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for LicenseVisitor {
    type Value = License;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("an existing license id")
    }

    fn visit_seq<A: SeqAccess<'de>>(self, mut access: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error> {
        let license_id = access.next_element::<&str>()?.unwrap_or(Default::default());
        let path = format!("licenses/{0}/{0}.yaml", &license_id);
        let config = std::fs::File::open(&path)
            .map_err(A::Error::custom)?;
        let mut license: License = serde_yaml::from_reader(&config)
            .map_err(A::Error::custom)?;
        license.id = license_id;

        Ok(license)
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for License {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_seq(LicenseVisitor{})
    }
}
```

Which does compile, but left me with a strange error:

```
Error: Message("invalid type: string \"gpl_2_0\", expected an existing license id", Some(Pos { marker: Marker { index: 208, line: 9, col: 4 }, path: "sources[0].licenses[0]" }))
```

Printing the resulting path to the license config and loading the same file manually in the main works without any problems.

Finally, I am not sure how I should pass a Vector to any of these approaches to be used to hold the licenses and avoid repeated loading of the licenses. Is this the approach to go and how can I extend this to fit my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Using a reader is normally incompatible with zero copy deserialization in serde, since there exists no buffer from which could be borrowed. This is a problem here `let license_ids: Vec<&str>`. Try deserializing a `Vec<String>`. This might be the problem in the second approach too.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error and I can now load the license, however how would you inject a vector into the function to load the license only if not already loaded?

Comment: Maybe you can implement `DeserializeSeed` instead of deriving `Deserialize`. The crate `serde_state` might also work for you.